# Puppeteer will not open chrome (getting error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an elastic-beanstalk instance on AWS and am trying to build a pdf export functionality on a dashboard using Puppeteer. I got the application to work locally, however when i run the export feature on the cloud i get the following error.

> (node:1434) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
>   /var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-674921/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

To deploy i am zipping the contents of the application (without the node modules fails upload if included) and deploying on the following configuration:

```
Environment tier:
Web Server

Platform:
Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.10.1

Health status:
Ok
```

I had struggled to get the application to deploy until i included a `.npmrc` file. However now i am having trouble running the functionality.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60904111/3645650

Answer (score 1):

Looks you are missing some Debian dependencies hope this [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/807#issuecomment-330056692) helps.