# installing puppeteer 2 elastickbeanstalk

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puppeteer

I can't deploy [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/) on aws AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to launch the browser process!\n/var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0)\n/var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libatspi.so.0)\n/var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: symbol lookup error: /var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: [https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md%5Cn%22)

Did anyone had the same issue and managed to solve it?

Comment: I have the same similar issue, nothing it worked regarding chromium package for Playwright. Can someone please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74696909/error-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-using-playwrightcrawler-package

Answer (score 3):

finally I solved it with this:

```
packages:
  yum:
    compat-libtiff3: []

commands:
  chrome:
    command: curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
```

Comment: this did not work for me and sent an error: `Failed to launch the browser process!\n/var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-809590/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libgbm.so.1`

Comment: This worked for me, after setting executablePath: 

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, executablePath: '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome' }) `

Comment: @Federico in my case, I didn't have to specify `executablePath`, running Puppeteer 21.5.1. Maybe it picks it up automatically in the newer version. I had to add the `-k` flag to the cURL command, though. The website's certificate had expired. Also I didn't need `compat-libtiff3` in my `.ebextensions/browser.config` file, as the main answer states.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a number of shared libs, see https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/765#issuecomment-358111805
You will also need 'sudo yum install -y mesa-libgbm.x86_64'
And looks like it works only for puppeteer2.0.0, later version fails with https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5379

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following post-build script after trying a whole bunch of different packages / versions.

Tested on Amazon Linux 2, Node.JS v16, puppeteer v15.3.0

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Put this in your Amazon Elastic Beanstalk repo 
# Tested on Amazon Linux 2, Node.JS v16, puppeteer v15.3.0
# File path: .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_install_libs.sh

sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y

cd node_modules/puppeteer/
cd .local-chromium/linux-*/chrome-linux
sudo yum install cups-libs dbus-glib libXrandr libXcursor libXinerama cairo cairo-gobject pango libnss3-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libxss-dev libcups2
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps --replacepkgs http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.28.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/at-spi2-atk-2.26.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/at-spi2-core-2.28.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/g/GConf2-3.2.6-7.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-6.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libxkbcommon-0.3.1-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libwayland-client-1.2.0-3.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libwayland-cursor-1.2.0-3.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/g/gtk3-3.10.4-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.0-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum install -y chromium
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/lucashenning/8f6807eab8b5d99caafd2a507f770ba1

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me !

Connected remotly via SSH in elastic beanstalk

`eb ssh {environment_name}`

Install Google Chrome

`curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash`

Source :
https://dev.to/achimoraites/a-developers-guide-to-run-puppeteer-on-elastic-beanstalk-no-ubuntu-linux-4pl5