# Failed to install Puppeteer and Chromium with Bit-bucket's pipeline to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puppeteer, bitbucket-pipelines

I deploy a Node.js express with Bitbucket's pipeline to AWS Elastic beanstalk.

The code includes installation of [Puppeteer `v5.0.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)
which downloads Chromium when installed.

> The deployment fails due to access permissions when downloading Chromium, see it below:
> ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r756035! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
> '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium'

How can I set permissions to make the installation completed successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installing puppeteer 2 elastickbeanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904111/installing-puppeteer-2-elastickbeanstalk)

Answer (score 2):

> GitHub repository maintained @ https://github.com/amarinediary/Marionette. The following might not be up to date. Refer to the GitHub link for a maintained version.

---

You can add AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration files (`.ebextensions`) to your web application's source code to configure your environment and customize the AWS resources that it contains.

In our case, if we don't enable [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#What_is_Extra_Packages_for_Enterprise_Linux_.28or_EPEL.29.3F) and if we continue installing Chromium as part of npm install, Puppeteer cannot launch Chromium due to unavailability of `libatk-1.0.so.0`.

- Source @ [Running Puppeteer on AWS EC2 instance running Amazon-Linux](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-aws-ec2-instance-running-amazon-linux)

### Hotfix

Add the following to your app root:

1. Create a `.npmrc` file.
2. Add the following to your `.npmrc` file:

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

The `.npmrc` file defines how npm should behave when running commands. Setting `unsafe-perm` to `true` suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. Set the unsafe-perm flag to run scripts with root privileges.

- Source @ [unsafe-perm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#unsafe-perm)

3. Create a `.ebextensions` folder.
4. Inside `.ebextensions` folder, create a `01_enableEPEL.config` file and add the following.

```
commands:
  01_enableEPEL:
    command: sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

5. Inside `.ebextensions` folder, create a `02_installEPELPackages.config` file and add the following

```
packages:
  yum:
    chromium: []
```

Comment: great answer! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just add .npmrc file in the root of your nodeAPP with this content:

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

this will force NPM to attempt to always run within the context of the running script. So you will not be blocked by the 'permission denied'