# puppeteer not working on vps but running locally

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, vps

I wrote a little puppeteer program that let me log into twitter and check a few things. Locally on mac OS Catalina, it is working but on VPS ubuntu 18.04 lts not working. And shows me a log at the start:

```
/root/retwiter/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-800071/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have 2 running configs for browser:
local:

```
{
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
        '--window-size=1920,1080'
    ]
}
```

vps:

```
{
    headless: true,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installing puppeteer 2 elastickbeanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904111/installing-puppeteer-2-elastickbeanstalk)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

i think you are missing the library **libnss3** , try to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-dev
```

and if that's not enough install all the deps for puppeteer

```
sudo apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget libgbm-dev
```

Comment: yup i did it but now I have problem with this `/root/retwiter/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-800071/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
But I can't even install it

Comment: try to install this 
sudo apt-get install libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libnss3-tools
puppeter has a lot of deps in the background that's why

Comment: if that don't work insstall of the deps here from pupetter docs :

sudo apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

Comment: I had fixed it by running program and installing one by one missing package and now it is working. Thanks

Comment: In my case I needed to install these packages:
sudo apt install libnss3
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0
sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-0
sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb1
sudo apt-get install libxcb-dri3-0
sudo apt-get install libxcomposite1 
sudo apt-get install libxdamage1
sudo apt-get install libxfixes3
sudo apt-get install libcups2
sudo apt-get install libdrm2
sudo apt-get install libxrandr2
sudo apt-get install libgbm1
sudo apt-get install libasound2
sudo apt-get install libpangocairo-1.0-0
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0

Answer (score 4):

If on CentOS, you can use this command with the correct dependencies:

```
sudo yum install -y alsa-lib.x86_64 atk.x86_64 cups-libs.x86_64 gtk3.x86_64 ipa-gothic-fonts libXcomposite.x86_64 libXcursor.x86_64 libXdamage.x86_64 libXext.x86_64 libXi.x86_64 libXrandr.x86_64 libXScrnSaver.x86_64 libXtst.x86_64 pango.x86_64 xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic xorg-x11-fonts-misc xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-utils

sudo yum update nss -y
```

Comment: ```couldn't find a match: ipa-gothic-fonts```

Answer (score 2):

You can add AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration files (`.ebextensions`) to your web application's source code to configure your environment and customize the AWS resources that it contains.

In our case, if we don't enable [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#What_is_Extra_Packages_for_Enterprise_Linux_.28or_EPEL.29.3F) and if we continue installing Chromium as part of npm install, Puppeteer cannot launch Chromium due to unavailability of `libatk-1.0.so.0`.

- Source @ [Running Puppeteer on AWS EC2 instance running Amazon-Linux](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-aws-ec2-instance-running-amazon-linux)

### Hotfix

Add the following to your app root:

1. Create a `.npmrc` file.
2. Add the following to your `.npmrc` file:

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

The `.npmrc` file defines how npm should behave when running commands. Setting `unsafe-perm` to `true` suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. Set the unsafe-perm flag to run scripts with root privileges.

- Source @ [unsafe-perm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#unsafe-perm)

3. Create a `.ebextensions` folder.
4. Inside `.ebextensions` folder, create a `01_enableEPEL.config` file and add the following.

```
commands:
  01_enableEPEL:
    command: sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

5. Inside `.ebextensions` folder, create a `02_installEPELPackages.config` file and add the following

```
packages:
  yum:
    chromium: []
```

> You can view the same guide on my GitHub @ https://github.com/amarinediary/Marionette